# forcing a list to be recomputed

Tags: list, haskell, memory-management

The function `search` below searches for two inputs which have the same output under some function. During the search it iterates over the input list `xs` twice, and this input list could be very large, e.g. `[0..1000000000]`. I'd rather use memory for storing the HashSet created by collision rather than storing the elements of `xs`, and my understanding is that even though `xs` could be lazily computed it would be kept around in case it was needed for the call to `find`.

Questions:

- is this understanding correct?
- if I keep it as a list is there a way I can have `xs` recomputed if it is passed to `find`?
- is there an alternative data structure I can use for `xs` which allows me to control the space used? `xs` is just used to specify which inputs to check.

Note that there are no type restrictions on `xs` - it can be a collection of any type.

```
import Data.HashSet as Set
import Data.Hashable
import Data.List

search :: (Hashable b, Eq b) => (a->b) -> [a] -> Maybe (a,a)
search h xs =
  do x0 <- collision h xs
     let h0 = h x0
     x1 <- find (\x -> (h x) == h0) xs
     return (x0,x1)

collision :: (Hashable b, Eq b) => (a->b) -> [a] -> Maybe a
collision h xs = go Set.empty xs
  where
    go s [] = Nothing
    go s (x:xs) =
      if y `Set.member` s
        then Just x
        else go (Set.insert y s) xs
      where y = h x

main = print $ search (\x -> x `mod` 21)  ([10,20..2100] :: [Int])
```

Comment: Did you really mean ``x1 <- find (\x -> (h x) `Set.member` s) xs`` and not `h x == h0`?

Comment: good catch - that's a lot simpler

Comment: You might be able to adapt the ideas in [Beautiful Folding](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html) to produce beautiful scanning.

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, by the way, you should be able to do it in a single pass over `xs` regardless. Just switch from a set to a map. This takes a bit more memory, of course, but shouldn't change the space complexity...

Comment: true, but this is a time/space trade-off decision, and in this case I don't mind spending extra time so that I can build a bigger HashSet and increase the probability of finding a collision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered basically this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209279/371753

Here's the relevant code.

```
import Data.Stream.Branching(Stream(..))
import qualified Data.Stream.Branching as S
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List

data UM s a = UM (s -> Maybe a) deriving Functor
type UStream s a = Stream (UM s) a

runUM s (UM f) = f s
liftUM x = UM $ const (Just x)
nullUM = UM $ const Nothing

buildUStream :: Int -> Int -> Stream (UM ()) Int
buildUStream start end = S.unfold (\x -> (x, go x)) start
    where go x
           | x < end = liftUM (x + 1)
           | otherwise = nullUM

usToList x = unfoldr (\um -> (S.head &&& S.tail) <$> runUM () um) x
```

Long story short, instead of passing around a list, pass around a data type that describes how to generate a list. Now you can write functions directly over the stream, or you can use the `usToList` function to use the list functions you already have.